# What is ACTUALLY the right way to transition/redirect using React Router?

Tags: react-router, reactjs, jsx

I'm in the process of learning React Router, and I can't seem to figure out what is *currently* the recommended way to redirect. I've read many articles and StackOverflow posts, but there is so much variety that I'm unsure of which one to implement for the current version of React Router.

What I'm trying to do is to redirect after an AJAX call using axios.

```
axios.post('/some-route')
    .then(/*I want to redirect here*/)
```

Note: this code lives inside a function, inside a React.Component, that is called upon the submission of a form.

How do I accomplish this?

Please kindly let me know what details you need.

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `browserHistory` :

```
  import { browserHistory } from "react-router";

  browserHistory.push({
     pathname: '/your/path'
  });
```

Comment: in v4 there is a history passed in the route, then you can use it in the compoenent as this.props.history.push('/routesample/');

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is for `react-router-v4`.

If you want to `redirect` from the same `component` (not from some `action`) and this `component` is rendered by some `route` then you can use `history` object passed in the `props`.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.state.some_param){
        this.props.history.push("/some_location")
    }
}
```

Best way is to create your own `history` object. You can use this `history` object in any `action`.

```
//history.js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export default createHistory()
```

then you can use this history in your router,

```
import history from "./history"

<Router history = {history}>
    //other code
</Router>
```

now you can use this history object anywhere for redirect,

```
axios.post('/some-route')
.then(res=>{
    history.push("/some_location")
})
```

```js
const {Component} = React
const {render} = ReactDOM

const {Router, Link, Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect} = ReactRouterDOM

const createHistory = History.createHashHistory

const myhistory = createHistory()

class App extends Component{
  redirectToHome(){
    myhistory.push("/home")
  }
  redirectToAbout(){
    myhistory.push("/about")
  }
  render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
      <Route path = "/about" component = {About} />
      <button onClick = {this.redirectToHome}>Redirect to home</button>
      <button onClick = {this.redirectToAbout}>Redirect to about</button>
    </div>
  )
  }
}

const Home = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      Home
    </div>
  )
}

const About = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>About</div>
  )
}


render(<Router history = {myhistory}><App/></Router>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.1.1/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history/4.6.3/history.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I did as you suggested: created a history.js file and import it whenever I need it. So, now doing history.push changes the URL, but nothing changes in the view. Any ideas on why this might happen?

Comment: @GregyPooh did you passed the `history` object to `router` ?

Comment: @GregyPooh Also use `Router` not `BrowserRouter`, if you are using your own  `history`.

Comment: why does this work for `Router`, but not `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @GregyPooh `BrowserRouter` creates its own [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js#L19), it wont use the history passed as props.

Comment: Why not use BrowerRouter with its built-in history? Pros? Cons?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from React Router v4, `browserHistory` is no longer exported from `react-router`.

You have two possibilities.

1) If your component is rendered via a route (is the `component` prop of a `<Route>` component, then you automatically get a few objects as props:

- history
- match
- location

You can then use `this.props.history.push("/some_location")` in the context of the component

2) If your component is not related to a specific route, you can get the same props by using the `withRouter` high order component, which is part of `react-router`

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = ( { history, location, match } ) => (
// your component code
);

export default withRouter(Component);
```